# Would it be possible to use electrically charged plasma to drive a vehicle to space?

Tags: fuel

Electrically charged plasma is not extremely difficult, at least in materials needed. I was wondering if it would be a practical substance due to its high energy. I also thought that, if it remained in a cloud after use, it may be collected with an electromagnet.

Comment: Hi @Thomas it looks like there are answers to that other question that answer your question as well. Have a look and if you think there's something here that is unanswered, it would be good to edit your question to emphasize that. If your question is closed as duplicate, it's not the end of the world. It means that your question will help to bring future readers to those answers. *Welcome to Space!*